# Duplicate Entry in Vbnet SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have been entering the same `username`, but it is still saving to DB. What's wrong with my code?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO testing_mysql_vb(id,user_name) VALUES(NULL,'" & TextBox1.Text & "')"

    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        dbread.Close()

        If dbread.HasRows Then
            sql = "select from testing_mysql_vb where user_name = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
            MsgBox("Duplicate record!")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
        dbread.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    MsgBox("The User Name was saved.")
    TextBox1.Text = ""
```

Comment: "here's my code". Is there a question?

Comment: Create a unique index on the user_name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see that there might be any of two issues:

1. The username is not primary key or unique constraint, hence its
       allowing to save. OR
2. You are first inserting into DB and then checking whether that username exist into DB or not. It should be other way round.